# Question about MOSFET CS amplifier simulation

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, design, circuit-analysis

This is the project statement:
[image]

I have designed the circuit and it worked well. This is the circuit:
[image]

It contains 3 voltmeters and 1 ammeter as shown.

This is a plot for `vin = vG`, `vout = vD`, `vS` and `iDS`:

[image]

**The question is**: 
When I increase vin from +/- 100 mV to +/- 1 V, the plot becomes like this:

[image]

1- Why does `vout` become almost straight line when `vin` reaches its maximum values?

2- Why does `vout` become a straight line when `vin reaches its minimum values?

My guesses:

1- Because the MOSFET exits from the saturation region to the triode region.

2- Because the MOSFET becomes off.

I know my guesses -if they're correct- are brief and not enough (especially 1), so please provide me with detailed explanation about the reasons of the two cases

Answer (score 1):

Look at the voltage scale of your graph. You're hitting the limits of your voltage supply. The output can never be higher than 15V (V2) or lower than about 1.1V (due to the R1/R2 voltage divider).